# Jasmine testing - persistence of affixed elements and why clicks trigger more than once

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Please note this is SPECIFIC to test environment using Jasmine. I am NOT having these issues in dev mode. Here's a bare bones example I created:

Code

```
function mountTest() {
  $(document).on("click", ".test", function() {
    console.log(">> clicked test")
  })
}
```

Spec code

```
fdescribe("test click test", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        test_btn = affix(".test")
        mountTest() /******************** KEY LINE ****************/
    })
    describe("1st spec", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            console.log(">>1")
            test_btn.click()
        })
        it("shoudl work", function(){

        })
    })
    describe("2nd spec", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            console.log(">>2")
            test_btn.click()
        })
        it("shoudl work", function(){

        })
    })
    describe("3rd spec", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            console.log(">>3")
            test_btn.click()
        })
        it("shoudl work", function(){

        })
        describe("4th spec", function() {
            beforeEach(function() {
                console.log(">>4")
                test_btn.click()
            })
            it("shoudl work", function(){

            })
        })
    })
})
```

As it stands, the output in console is this:

```
>>1
>> clicked test
>>2
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>>3
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>>3
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>>4
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
>> clicked test
```

I have discovered that the reason for the redundancy in clicks is because `mountTest()` is called at the top-level `beforeEach`. Further experimentation has revealed that if `mountTest()` is called within one of the `describe` blocks that is a spec (1, 2, 3, 4), then the redundancy is removed for ALL specs AFTER the first spec on which the `mountTest()` is placed. FOR EXAMPLE

Modified spec code

```
fdescribe("test click test", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        test_btn = affix(".test")
    })
    describe("1st spec", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            console.log(">>1")
            test_btn.click()
        })
        it("shoudl work", function(){

        })
    })
    describe("2nd spec", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            console.log(">>2")
            mountTest() /******************** KEY LINE ****************/
            test_btn.click()
        })
        it("shoudl work", function(){

        })
    })
    describe("3rd spec", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            console.log(">>3")
            test_btn.click()
        })
        it("shoudl work", function(){

        })
        describe("4th spec", function() {
            beforeEach(function() {
                console.log(">>4")
                test_btn.click()
            })
            it("shoudl work", function(){

            })
        })
    })
})
```

Console output

```
>>1
>>2
>> clicked test
>>3
>> clicked test
>>3
>> clicked test
>>4
>> clicked test
```

The redundancy is gone. The 1st spec doesn't trigger any clicks because the `mountTest()` is not called until the 2nd spec.

Can someone explain this behavior to me? I don't even begin to know what I'm misunderstanding here... is it the nature of the `affix` or the `beforeEach` or...?

Here are some of my questions in looking at this:

1. In the modified spec example, if `mountTest()` is only called in the 2nd spec `describe` block, why are the clicks for the 3rd/4th specs working? How did `mountTest()` translate over? My only thought would be that somehow the `affix(".test")` element keeps the `eventHandler` added by `mountTest()`, but according to `jasmine-fixture` docs (https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture), affix cleans up its own elements after each spec?
2. In the original spec example, I think the explanation for why the clicks are so redundant is that `mountTest()` has mounted N times by the Nth spec, so at Nth spec, each click registers once for each mount, so you get Nth clicks. But overlapping with #1, if the `affix(".test")` element is new each time, then you're mounting on a new object each time, so it should only trigger once, no?

FWIW, to test the affix, I did manually write a `afterEach(function() { $(".test").remove() })` and add it after each `it` expectation block in the original spec code, and this did NOT fix the issue at all.

Relevant gemfile:

```
gem 'jasmine', "2.6"
gem 'jasmine-jquery-rails' # resolving to 2.0.3
```

Then also `jasmine-fixture` is loading via a file `spec > javascripts > helpers > jasmine-fixture.min.js` which is requested because in the `spec > javascripts > support > jasmine.yml` file, there's a line:

```
src_files:
...
helpers:
  - 'helpers/**/*.js'
```

Comment: By any chance, do you have a `#jasmine_content` element on your HTML? Or maybe your runner has it... Also, what version of `jasmine-fixture` do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the listener is being attached to the document not the element that is managed by `affix`. This is why the listeners are not being removed and why removing the element manually doesn't do anything either. You would need to attach it directly to the element created. You could do:

```
function mountTest(el) {
  el.on("click", function() {
    console.log(">> clicked test")
  })
}
```

And call it this way:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    test_btn = affix(".test")
    mountTest(test_btn);
})
```

This will attach it directly on the element and not the `document`.

Comment: omg oh wow so simple. ok so the problem is that my code NEEDS it to be on the document (it's a listener for element dynamically added). so i guess i can build my own cleanup and remove listener on the document in an `afterEach`?

Comment: @james I would just mount the listener on a [`beforeAll`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.9/global.html#beforeAll) hook.

Comment: hmmm tried that. I mounted it in a `beforeAll` at the top line (right after first `describe` line), and then only the 1st spec click fired. Adding an `afterEach(function() { $(document).off })` after that first top line `beforeEach` block did work though. I would prefer the `beforeAll` approach but any insight why it didnt work?

Comment: You still need a `beforeEach` hook for the affix call. The `jasmine-fixture` package removes the element with each spec (across any suite, even those that don't even use it), so that can't be on a `beforeAll`.

Comment: so complicated!

Comment: Personally, I would definitely not use this library. It's just does so little and is coded poorly IMO. If it came to me between adding this dependency or just cleaning up after myself, I would do the latter. It's really not that complicated as they make it sound.

Comment: Also, just to clarify `.test` does not create an HTML button (you suffix your variable with `btn`) and it's a `div`. It uses `emmet` to expand `.test` into `<div class"test"></div>`

Comment: yes maybe one day i will remove throughout, but alas... ah yes I'm aware that it's all `divs` unless otherwise specified, but the behavior doesn't change so I'm OK with that

Answer (score 1):

@MinusFour answered correctly and I accepted, for process sake I just wanted to clarify the two possible answers that would work, based on explanation + commentary.

Option A:

```
describe("test click test", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        test_btn = affix(".test")
    })
    beforeAll(function(){
        mountTest()
    })
    ....
```

Option B:

```
describe("test click test", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        test_btn = affix(".test")
        mountTest()
    })
    afterEach(function() {
        $(document).off()
    })
    ....
```